# Realm .copyToRealmOrUpdate() causes duplicates to appear

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, realm

I have an `AsyncTask` that is used when user wants to manually reload his discussion messages (fetches 20 newest messages of every discussion the user has from our server). For some reason all of the messages fetched this way get duplicated. And every run of the task just creates more duplicates. First run creates no duplicates, but every run after that does... It's worth mentioning that I use socket.io to communicate with the server so the responses fire a new thread when received.

Discussion class

```
@PrimaryKey
private String discussion_id;

private RealmList<Message> messages;
// More declarations + generated getters & setters
```

Message class

```
@PrimaryKey
private String msgID;

private String message;
//Declarations + getters & setters
```

And here's the simplified part in the AsyncTask that saves the message information into the database.

```
 for (msgData : receivedMessages)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
       // Set all relevant data

        realm.beginTransaction();
        chat.getMessages().add(msg);
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chat);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    realm.beginTransaction();
    chat.setPreview(chat.getMessages().last().getMessage());
    chat.setLastMessage(chat.getMessages().last().getCreated());
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chat);
    realm.commitTransaction();

    realm.close();
```

I ran `Log.d("MESSAGES TOTAL","=="+chat.getMessages().size());` after every call of the AsyncTask and this is what I got.

```
D/MESSAGES TOTAL: ==20
D/MESSAGES TOTAL: ==40
D/MESSAGES TOTAL: ==60
```

To be sure I ran

```
String id =chat.getMessages().first().getMsgID();
long count = realm.where(Message.class).equalTo("msgID",id).count();
Log.d("FIRST ITEM ID", id+"- COUNT:"+count);
```

And got

```
D/FIRST ITEM ID: 56bb693593de502003681054- COUNT:1
```

Now that I dwelled this deep into madness, I printed every message in a chat to console and looked at the ID's and this is what I found.

```
02-10 20:08:38.097 13339-13339/com.dev.proto D/DISCUSSIONACTIVITY:: CREATED: Wed Feb 10 16:45:41 EET 2016--MSG ID: 56bb693593de502003681054
02-10 20:08:38.097 13339-13339/com.dev.proto D/DISCUSSIONACTIVITY:: CREATED: Wed Feb 10 16:45:41 EET 2016--MSG ID: 56bb693593de502003681054
02-10 20:08:38.107 13339-13339/com.dev.proto D/DISCUSSIONACTIVITY:: CREATED: Wed Feb 10 16:45:41 EET 2016--MSG ID: 56bb693593de502003681054
```

Three identical message ids. Something isn't working as intended now... Any ideas on how to fix this or how to debug this further?

Comment: Where do you get the `chat` variable from? Also note that if you do a `copyOrUpdate` it will also update your `messages` list. It does this by clearing it and adding all the new items, but it will not delete any messages that are no longer in the list as they might be referenced from elsewhere. This might be the reason you are seeing duplicates.

Comment: `chat` is retreived from realm just before the loop. I'll take a look into the library I'm using to display the results. It just might be that I do have references in the form of `RealmResult<Message>`. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: I never found a solution to this one, but we fixed the issue by changing the update logic on the server side. I might take a closer look into this when I have some free time on my hands...

Comment: This is all because this should have all been one transaction, and you should have created managed objects for this use case directly -  if you use managed RealmList and add managed RealmObject to it, then duplication won't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every time you add Message object in Chat which is wrong you have to replace message object in case of object with same massage_id found

```
Discussion mDiscussion = realm.where(Discussion.class).equalTo("id", DiscussionID).findFirst();          
Message mMessage = mDiscussion.getMessages().where().equalTo("id",updatedMessage.getId()).findFirst();
if(null!=mMessage&&  mDiscussion.getMessages().indexOf(mMessage)!=-1){
    //if Simmilar Message Object present in mDiscussion.getMessages() then replace
    mDiscussion.getMessages().set(mDiscussion.getMessages().indexOf(mMessage),taskfinal);
}else{
    //if not then add Message  to list
    mDiscussion.getMessages().add(taskfinal);
} 
 realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mDiscussion);
```

Hope this help you and other best of luck